# Is there an option in cdn.tailwindcss.com to re-compile its inline style on the fly?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I use [cdn.tailwindcss.com](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) JS-code for development purpose and I see that it adds inline style to the `<head>` with compiled CSS declarations for all Tailwind classes which are used on the current page.

Now I want to add a simple panel with `<input type="number">` so that if I change the input value, the corresponding Tailwind class would be changed.

For example suppose we have

```
<h1 class="mb-24">Heading</h1>
```

And I add my panel with event listener the way like

```
let panel = document.createElement('div');
panel.innerHTML = '<input type="number" step="1" value="24">';
panel.setAttribute('style', 'position:fixed;top:0;right:0;');
document.body.appendChild(panel);

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    let newMb = e.currentTarget.value;
    document.querySelector('h1').classList.replace('mb-24', 'mb-'+newMb);
});
```

When I change the input value for example to `23` or `25`, the class of the `h1` in the DOM is changed, but not visually because the cdn.tailwindcss.com doesn't re-compile its inline style at this moment.

Is it possible to force it to such re-compiling on the fly? And if so, then how to?

ps. As I can understand, it means Tailwind JIT in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it was my mistake

I've forgotten that after `16` the step for margin and padding in Tailwind classes is `4` and not `1`

Actually it DOES work on the fly